# Retrieving Inputstream image from servlet using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, servlets, inputstream

I want to retrieve an image from mysql/servlet out to jsp using jquery. I made servlet that retrieves object from mysql and parse it to json, and finally display object attributes using jquery.

After run the jsp I got string attributes but unfortunately my problem with the image which is broken. I think I have problem of showing inputstream image or I miss something. help Please

index.jsp

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">   
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
            {

        $.ajax
        ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "InfoServlet",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {


        $.each(data, function(i,data)
        {
            var msg_data= "<div id='msgdiv"+data.Msg+"'>"+data.IdInfo+" and "+data.Msg+"</div>";

            $(msg_data).appendTo("#content");
            $('#thediv').prepend('<img id="theImg" src='+data.Picture+' />');


        });

        }
        });


        return false;
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>


<div id='content'></div>
<div id='thediv'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/InfoServlet")
public class InfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public InfoServlet() 
{
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try
    {   
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    InfoService is = new InfoService();
    Info info = new Info();

    int idinfo = 2;
    info = is.queryById(idinfo);
    String gout= gson.toJson(info);
    System.out.println("{\"Messages\":"+gout+"}");
    out.println("{\"Messages\":"+gout+"}");
    //System.out.println(gout);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.close();
    }
}

}
```

Info object:

```
package net.test.service;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class Info
{
private int IdInfo;
private String Msg;
private InputStream Picture;


public int getIdInfo() {
    return IdInfo;
}
public void setIdInfo(int idInfo) {
    IdInfo = idInfo;
}
public InputStream getPicture() {
    return Picture;
}
public void setPicture(InputStream picture) {
    Picture = picture;
}
public String getMsg() {
    return Msg;
}
public void setMsg(String msg) {
    Msg = msg;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tree observations, first in the class Info the Picture member must be a byte[] array you can't use the stream, Second in the servlet when you return an json response the content type is response.setContentType("application/json");.
Third and the most important the attribute src in the img tag only supports the URL to the image file it can't receive bytes of an image.

I suggest you to read the image from the database create an temporary image file and send the url to be used in the img tag.

In a hybrid mobile application I render an image using javascript but this was a complicate process because you need to encode the bytes (base-64) and decode with javascript and use a library to render an image using this bytes.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Nice suggestion thank you, But If I go with your suggestion I think the temp image files will increase over the time, plus the stored image in the DB which means double the HD space.
Do you think That I have to change the code and store only the image url into the db instead of the image it self. The problem is that I built all my code to work with the stored database image as LongBlob, So if I decide to change that means I need to change all the code.
I will try to get the image from db as a byte[] array as you observed first and I will try to see if there is any potential to show the image.

Comment: I think the best solution is to store the url in your database and store the image in the folder of your site, sometimes the effort to refactor the code is the best solution to improve the performance and the maintainability.

Comment: Finally, I tried to work with Base64 to show the image and this was very convenient for me. Thank You

Comment: That's great, You are welcome, If you think it was helpful you could select this as correct answer.